# About hashing passwords with argon2i

Tags: php, security, hash

I set up a dev server and I installed nginx with php-fpm and 7.2 php (I installed all the necessary php packages).

The time has come to upgrade the security of all logins, using the argon2i algo.
So, I tried this (test code in dev enviroment. The security in the code, will come later):

```
require('connector.php');

$usr_u = $_POST['username'];
$psw_u = $_POST['password'];

$usr = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $usr_u);
$psw = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $psw_u);

$f_pass = password_hash($psw, PASSWORD_ARGON2I);

$result = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE username = '$usr'";
$tbl = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

$table = $tbl->fetch_assoc();
$m_user = $table['username'];

if ($m_user == $usr)
{
//correct username
    echo 'Correct username!<br>';

    $result = "SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE username = '$m_user'";
    $tbl = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

    $table = $tbl->fetch_assoc();
    $m_pass = $table['password'];


    if (password_verify($m_pass,$f_pass)) //always returns false
    {
        echo 'Password correct!<br>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Wrong password!<br>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Wrong username!<br>';
}
//close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
```

I always get "Correct username!" and "Wrong password!". I used echo on hashed password from the DB and from the input and I see that every time the hashed password is different. I assume that the hashing process, include using random salt and there is my issue.

As far as I understand, the random salt is necessary in order to retain the security of the hashing.

Can you please point me to the right direction, on how to solve this? I have the hashed password in my DB and I can't figure out a way to check the input password against the one in my DB (using password_verify and hash_equals).

Thank everyone in advance for the help.

Comment: `$psw = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $psw_u); $f_pass = password_hash($psw, PASSWORD_ARGON2I);` — Escape for the database just before you put it into the database, not just before you hash it! A password hash isn't a database!! (And don't escape manually anyway, use prepared statements / bound parameters)

Comment: Better yet, don't escape at all but use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [password_verify](http://php.net/password_verify):

> ```
> bool password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )
> ```

The first argument is the password but you are passing it *the hash you want to compare it to*.

The second argument is the hash you want to compare it to but you are passing it *a new hash created from user input*.

```
password_verify($_POST['password'], $m_pass)
```

Comment: that's it. Thank you very much for your help. When I read the documentation, I thought that I needed to pass the hashed password from the user. Thank you again.